# Channels: list API not returning all channels

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Channels: list API ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list ) to get all channels that are managedByMe & onBehalfOfContentOwner

The API, channels overview, and exporting all channels in YouTube CMS indicate 1172 channels

But when polling the API, I only end up with 1092 channels, even though the API itself returns 'totalResults': 1172

```
nextPageToken, channels = None, []
while channels == [] or nextPageToken is not None:
    results = service.channels().list(part='id', managedByMe=True, onBehalfOfContentOwner=CONTENT_OWNER_ID,
                                      maxResults=50, pageToken=nextPageToken).execute()
    channels.extend([item['id'] for item in results['items']])
    print(len(results['items']))
    nextPageToken = results.get('nextPageToken', None)
print(len(channels))
```

Output:

```
50
50
49
48
50
50
50
50
50
48
50
44
49
44
47
47
43
44
36
43
41
44
45
20
1092
```

Have I made some silly mistake, or is the API simply unreliable?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the missing channels is they are suspended!

Unfortunately the API documentation makes no mention of suspending channels being skipped in the API, even though they are included in totalResults

Nor is the suspended status included in the exported CSV